# Javascript Error, Uncaught TypeError Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, types

I'm trying to insert a script in a Joomla module. The script is a percentage loader in JS. I'm had some issues with another js but I finally managed to solve them.

The error i'm getting is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a
>   function (anonymous function)

I'm trying to import the [Percentage Loader jQuery plugin](http://widgets.better2web.com/loader/)

And the js code is:

```
$(function() {
  var $topLoader = $("#dttopLoader").percentageLoader({width: 256, height: 256, controllable : true, progress : 0.5, onProgressUpdate : function(val) {
      $topLoader.setValue(Math.round(val * 100.0));
    }});

  var topLoaderRunning = false;
  $("#dtanimateButton").click(function() {
    if (topLoaderRunning) {
      return;
    }
    topLoaderRunning = true;
    $topLoader.setProgress(0);
    $topLoader.setValue('0kb');
    var kb = 0;
    var totalKb = 999;

    var animateFunc = function() {
      kb += 17;
      $topLoader.setProgress(kb / totalKb);
      $topLoader.setValue(kb.toString() + 'kb');

      if (kb < totalKb) {
        setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);
      } else {
        topLoaderRunning = false;
      }
    }

    setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);

  });
});
```

I tried changing the first line from "$(function()..." to "jquery(function()..." as I read many topics on stackoverflow but still can't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery(function()...`, case-sensitive?

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your site?

Comment: I tried case-sensitive but still the same error.
Yes jQuery is already included.

Comment: @ManolisC.: Pitty Zach deleted his answer and I was a bit off with the syntax too, hence I deleted mine. Can you post what worked for you in the end please so we have a good answer? It would be very usefull for future users I think. You can also accept your own answers then after some waiting period.

Comment: @François: I assume what eventually worked was `jQuery(function($) {...});` (or it's longer equivalent). Key here is passing `$` as first argument. Although the OP claimed to have tried using `jQuery`, they probably didn't change every occurrence of `$`.  You should undelete your answer and just remove your edit.

Comment: How about the order in which your scripts are being loaded/called? Is jquery being loaded before this plugin, and executed after dom ready(if needed)?

Comment: Something might be taking the `$` variable before jQuery.

Comment: @FelixKling: I un-done the last edit and undeleted the answer now. I don't know now if that is actually what made it work in the end or not. I never had to work with jQuery in no-conflict mode before so I'm not 100% sure. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a similar issue in [**this SO post here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct) but in WordPress.

You said you are using Joomla. Joomla might also include the jQuery library loaded "no conflict" mode and perhaps the same solution can be applied.

Try replacing this:

```
$(function() {
```

With this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
```

Comment: Or just `jQuery(function($) {`

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Now it works!! Just added the (jQuery) at the end and now it shows up!

Sorry but i'm new here and I can't find Zachary's answer.
Francois that works too! Thank you!!

Comment: No, the second argument will just be ignored. It should not make a difference at all.

Comment: @ManolisC.: I un-done my last edit as it only added confusion. Let me know if that is acceptable now.