# Toggle click function not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, menu, cursor, toggle

Not a web developer, so be easy on me. I've tried real hard to get a list of archives on this right-hand sidebar to toggle – http://my-table.com/sidedish.

It seems to be working fine on desktop, but nothing happens when trying to click it on mobile.

Two questions:

1) How to I get a pointer/cursor to appear when hovering over the "SideDish Archives" so people know this is an active link?

2) How do I get this toggle function to work on a mobile device?

JQuery I have for the toggle function:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.side-archive-list h2', function () {jQuery('.side-archive-list ul').toggle(); });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1)  This should do it:

```
.side-archive-list:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

2) I tested it on my browser's mobile phone simulator, and the toggle works just fine on the mobile version. Try increasing the clickable area by using padding? [This person had the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559179/jquery-toggle-not-working-on-mobile) with toggling on mobile, because it was accidentally calling toggle twice. They fixed it by removing existing listeners before adding a new one by using the off() call.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! And the cursor is working, thank you! I've actually looked at that thread today, and tried using off() call, but since I know basically nothing about JQuery, I probably did something wrong. I'll look through it again. ** I tried adding padding and it still doesn't click on my iPhone **

Comment: If anyone has any other suggestions/ideas of what could be happening, I'm still stuck!