# When I click on an anchor in mobile the toggle function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make it so when I click on the facebook icon, a dialog opens in which you can see the feed of a certain page.

So basically I want to make a function (with jQuery) that toggles the visibility of an iframe (generated from Facebook).

This is working on my website: https://sjaeloglegeme.dk/, but on on mobile - when I tap on the Facebook icon the iframe doesn't "show itself".

I created a JSFiddle to show you my code but because of some reason it isn't even working on my pc. I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

https://jsfiddle.net/s4yf0tq1/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="fb"><img src="https://vanineveld.github.io/sjaeloglegeme/img/fb.svg" alt="facebook logo"></a>

<iframe id="fbDialog" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsjaeloglegeme%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" width="340" height="500" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#fb {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

#fb img {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
}

#fbDialog {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 30px;
  display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#fb').on('click', function() {
    $('#fbDialog').toggle();
});
```

Comment: You should be using a button here. Anchors are for linking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559179/jquery-toggle-not-working-on-mobile/17560244)?

Or maybe try adding event.preventDefault() in your code like this:

```
$('#fb').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#fbDialog').toggle();
});
```

Comment: A front-end developer should know to [never link the word "here"](https://www.sitepoint.com/15-rules-making-accessible-links/).

Comment: thanks, didn't know that, maybe because 'im not a front-end .. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your https://sjaeloglegeme.dk/ website from my mobile. The iframe is completely working. or you could change the #fb position: absolute; to show it over the container.