# JavaScript File not Working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a div that I want the height set to the same size as the width, so I added a javascript file that looks like this

```
var cw = $('.block-me').width();
$('.block-me').css({
    'height': cw + 'px'
});
```

to my javascript files. When I load the page the height is not being added in the code, however the file is being called in the head.

I am using the Jetpack plugin's CSS editor so I'm wondering if I have to specify which css file to add too or what?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the Function Reference/wp enqueue script, but I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've just entered it here with a typo, I think it's just an extra `:` in your code:

```
var cw = $('.block-me').width();
$('.block-me').css({
    'height': cw + 'px'
});
```

You have `'height:':` and it should be `'height':`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xHDEX/)

Comment: I had that typo in the code, but removing the extra : didn't fix the problem :/

Comment: If that isn't working, then there must not be an element present with the class `.block-me` or it doesn't have a width defined.

Comment: I think it has something to do with me using a % value for the width. Is there a way to convert the % to px after the page loads?

Comment: Here is the code I'm working with, made a couple changes. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/redf150flames/DKFFT/1/)

Comment: In that link, you'll need to change your `.block-me` to `#block-me` (id selector vs class selector), and the add jquery to the frameworks on the left. I've updated [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/DKFFT/2/)

Comment: There must be other factors being introduced by other js files or css or something that you aren't showing. As you can see by the fiddle, the code shown works.

Comment: Those "other factors" are what I was asking about.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what your wordpress environment might be doing to this code.

Comment: Its not anything in the other js files because everything I am doing is a custom addition, so the answer should be something general that would be the case with any wordpress site

Comment: Again, without seeing all of the relevant code, I can only guess. And I'll guess that there is an issue with the element in question. It either doesn't have a width or you are trying to get the width via the wrong selector.

Comment: All the code I'm using on WordPress is the code we used on Fiddle, character for character, minus the alert. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DKFFT/2/)

Comment: So, keep the alert. See what you get. The fiddle works so then your html must not have an element with class `.block-1` or id `.block-me` anywhere.

Comment: The HTML has both the class block-1 and id block-me. Here is the code from my homepage source `<div id="blocks">
<div class="block-1" id="block-me">
</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with uploading a JavaScript/jQuery file to WordPress is the file needs to be coded for no-conflict mode.

The answer on this question is what helped me find the answer [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct).

Basically anywhere you use a **$** in jquery on WordPress you need to write **jQuery**

Comment: No, you don't have to do that.  Just wrap your code in a self-invoking function that passes `jQuery` as the value of a param named `$`.