# jQuery won't run on development site, but works on online code editors. Can't find conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict

I am having an issue with jQuery where I can get it to work on different testing environments, but not on my development site. I can't seem to find the conflict or what would be causing it.

How it should work: When you hover over the icons, it changes the visible div above. I have it working here: http://codepen.io/redbranchmedia/pen/dkiCB and here: http://jsfiddle.net/nXzFX/

HTML:

```
<div class="outercontainer">
<div class="slidecontainer slide1">
    <div class="innercontainer">
        <img class="productimg" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/300x250default.png" />
        <div class="prodpara"><h2>Talemetry</h2><p>is a cloud software solution that provides recruiters with all the tools they need to find, attract &amp; engage top talent. Talemetry works with your Applicant Tracking System and recruiting service providers to deliver a complete talent acquisition solution to support today’s recruiting challenges.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ctabutton"> 
            <p class="ctatext">Put the Power of Talent Generation to Work At Your Work.</p>
            <img class="ctaline" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/vertical_line.png">
            <h3 class="ctaaction">Let's Talk >></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer slide2 hiddenslide">
    <div class="innercontainer">
        <img class="productimg" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/300x250default.png" />
        <div class="prodpara"><h2>Source &amp; CRM</h2><p>Search across all sources of hire, find and rank candidates for immediate job openings, all while building talent networks for the future.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ctabutton"> 
            <p class="ctatext">Significantly reduce sourcing time and improve recruiter efficiency.</p>
            <img class="ctaline" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/vertical_line.png">
            <h3 class="ctaaction">Request a Demo >></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer slide3 hiddenslide">
    <div class="innercontainer">
        <img class="productimg" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/300x250default.png" />
        <div class="prodpara"><h2>Job Broadcast</h2><p>Post, manage, and compare the effectiveness of job postings across hundreds of job boards and social media sites all from one system.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ctabutton"> 
            <p class="ctatext">Significantly reduce sourcing time and improve recruiter efficiency.</p>
            <img class="ctaline" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/vertical_line.png">
            <h3 class="ctaaction">Request a Demo >></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer slide4 hiddenslide">
    <div class="innercontainer">
        <img class="productimg" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/300x250default.png" />
        <div class="prodpara"><h2>Career Sites</h2><p>Promote jobs and strengthen your employer brand by building career sites using a simple Content Management System.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ctabutton"> 
            <p class="ctatext">Deliver your employer brand every- where with Talemetry Career Sites.</p>
            <img class="ctaline" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/vertical_line.png">
            <h3 class="ctaaction">Request a Demo >></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slidecontainer slide5 hiddenslide">
    <div class="innercontainer">
        <img class="productimg" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/300x250default.png" />
        <div class="prodpara"><h2>Apply</h2><p>Capture more of the best applicants by creating a simple, integrated, and social and mobile-ready application process.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ctabutton"> 
            <p class="ctatext">Significantly reduce sourcing time and improve recruiter efficiency.</p>
            <img class="ctaline" src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/vertical_line.png">
            <h3 class="ctaaction">Request a Demo >></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="iconcontainer">
    <div class="icon icon1" data-slide="slide1">
        <img src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/talemetry_icon2.png">
        <p>Talemetry</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon2" data-slide="slide2">
        <img src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/source_and_crm.png">
        <p>Source &amp; CRM</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon3" data-slide="slide3">
        <img src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/job_broadcast.png">
        <p>Job Broadcast</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon4" data-slide="slide4">
        <img src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/career_sites.png">
        <p>Career Sites</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon5" data-slide="slide5">
        <img src="http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/apply.png">
        <p>Apply</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outercontainer {
    width:100%;
}

.slidecontainer {
    width:100%;
    height:285px;
}

.slidecontainer.hiddenslide {
    display:none;
}

.slidecontainer.slide1 {
background-color:#b7be10;
}

.slidecontainer.slide2 {
background-color:#374bb5;
}

.slidecontainer.slide3 {
background-color:#ef123e;
}

.slidecontainer.slide4 {
background-color:#efae00;
}

.slidecontainer.slide5 {
background-color:#9d5bb6;
}

.slidecontainer .innercontainer {
    max-width:940px;
}

img.productimg {
    float:right;
}

.prodpara > H2 {
    font-size:30px;
    color:#fff;
}

.prodpara > p {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
}

.ctabutton p.ctatext {
    font-size:15px;
}

p.ctaline {
    font-size:;
}

h3.ctaaction {
    font-size:20px;
}

.iconcontainer {
    max-width:940px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.iconcontainer .icon {
    float:left;
    width:90px;
    text-align: center;
}

.iconcontainer .icon p {
    color:#585858;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('.iconcontainer .icon').on(
{
    mouseenter: function()
    {
        $('.outercontainer .slidecontainer').addClass('hiddenslide');
        var show_slide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        $('.' + show_slide).removeClass('hiddenslide');
    }
});
</script>
```

I can't get it to work on my development site here (where I want it): http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/

I also set it up on a test page because I thought maybe the slider was interfering: http://talemetry.redbranchmedia.com/testing-page/

Unfortunately, it isn't working anywhere on the development site, but it is working on the JSFiddle and CodePen sites.

I've tried numerous things including:
 Calling different versions of jQuery from the Google Developer Libraries
 Calling in jQuery internally on the site
 Replacing the "    $    " in my script with "jQuery" (the theme authors seem to have done this)
and much, much more.

I'm at a loss for what's causing the conflict and preventing this from running. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I didn't have enough characters to insert my PHP code, so here are the links to those: 
Header PHP: http://pastebin.com/V5KVRiSf
Body PHP: http://pastebin.com/UVtAmzmH
Footer PHP: http://pastebin.com/uQp92bVN

Comment: Probably just aren't waiting till the element exists to run the code. Can't confirm without seeing errors (sorry, i won't follow that link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSFiddle and CodePen both generally wait for the dom ready event to run your code.

If your code is working on these sites, I'd suggest wrapping your code in a $(document).ready() block, ie:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.iconcontainer .icon').on(
  {
    mouseenter: function()
    {
        $('.outercontainer .slidecontainer').addClass('hiddenslide');
        var show_slide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        $('.' + show_slide).removeClass('hiddenslide');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, this didn't work. I also put tried it in the footer (where it is at this exact moment) and that didn't help either. I'd love to hear any other ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I take that back. Your script is working. I had to change the first "$" to "jQuery" and add "$" in the parentheses after the function call per this post I found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try encasing in `DOM` ready handler

```
$(function () {
    $('.iconcontainer .icon').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('.outercontainer .slidecontainer').addClass('hiddenslide');
            var show_slide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
            $('.' + show_slide).removeClass('hiddenslide');
        }
    });
});
```

Your script is declared before the `body` and the elements are not yet available in the `DOM` . So event is bound to an empty `jQuery Object`. Encasing your code inside `DOM` handler makes sure the elements are available in the `DOM` before any events are bound. If not you can move the script to just before the closing tag of body.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this didn't work. I tried it in the header and footer right before the closing body tag. (that's where it sits at this moment if you want to take a look). I tried both your script and the other, but with no luck. I'd love to hear any other ideas you might have. Thanks!

Comment: Also check that your console was throwing some errors. Try fixing them first if you want the code to work. Also I don't see jQuery being included on the page. That should be the first library that should be included if you are using any of the jQuery plugins

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing that out. (I should've double-checked). I found this post after your last comment which showed me that I had a syntax error due to starting that script with "$" rather than jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct

Comment: @jphogan.. Glad to have helped :)