# Correct jQuery markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, markup

How would I write the following code to jQuery?

```
       $("select").change(function(){
    if($("#selectedid").is(":selected")){
        $("#showblock").slideDown("slow");
    } else { $("#showblock").slideUp("slow"); } 
});
```

I also tried the following:

```
jQuery("select").change(function($){
        if($("#selectedid").is(":selected")){
            $("#showblock").slideDown("slow");
        } else { $("#showblock").slideUp("slow"); } 
    });
```

It's for wordpress.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "write the following code to jQuery?"  Please try to be more specific

Comment: Depending on the situation, a simple toggle("slow") could be enough

Comment: Sorry I edit the code a bit. However the problem is that wordpress will give this code an error. As `Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function `

Comment: can you share the html for the `select`

Comment: what is the error you're getting? inspect element in chrome and paste the error here please

Comment: can you share a link to the website with us so we can check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object \[object Window\] is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wordpress you'll probably get errors because wordpress includes a version of jquery that is editted to not use the '$' operator

you have to replace every instance of the '$' with `jQuery`
so your code should look like this;

```
jQuery("select").change(function(){
    if(jQuery("#selectedid").is(":selected")){
        jQuery("#showblock").slideDown("slow");
    } else { 
        jQuery("#showblock").slideUp("slow"); 
    } 
});
```

try that and tell me how it works for you.

an easier way would be just to include a standard (downloaded) version of jquery and include it in your header.php

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick.. I thought I could give the function a $ variable

Answer (score 1):

I think it happening because You have to resolve the conflict for `"$"`

From [Word Press Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just wrap your code into immediately invoking function and pass Jquery to it.

```
(function($) {

    $("select").change(function(){
       if($("#selectedid").is(":selected")){
           $("#showblock").slideDown("slow");
       } else { 
           $("#showblock").slideUp("slow");
       } 
  });

})(jQuery);
```