# 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document).on')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this script:

```
<script>
var original_value = Number($('#ProductPrice').text().replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,""));

$(document).on('keyup', '#ProductPrice', function() {
if (Number($('#ProductPrice').text().replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,"")) > original_value) {
    $("#ProductPrice").css("color","red");
} else {
    $("#ProductPrice").css("color", "black");   
}
});
</script>
```

I keep getting an error:'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document).on')

Help?

Comment: What version of jquery you are using? I guess on is not available for the versions earlier to 1.7

Comment: Is anything conflicting/overwriting jQuery's `$` (ex. prototype)?

Comment: @Sergio, it is built into our CMS, BigCommerce, so yes, it is loaded correct.

Comment: I was unable to get this script to work without breaking lots of things, but I did come up with a solution. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling you have jQuery in *no  conflict mode*, which means the $ is not assigned to jQUery

You can call your code like this:

```
(function ($) {
    var original_value = Number($('#ProductPrice').text().replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, ""));
    $(document).on('keyup', '#ProductPrice', function () {
        if (Number($('#ProductPrice').text().replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, "")) > original_value) {
            $("#ProductPrice").css("color", "red");
        } else {
            $("#ProductPrice").css("color", "black");
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

You can also just replace all the `$` with `jQuery`;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are taking the value as input from user in a text box.
You need to have a value and not text for the input type text.

```
var original_value = Number($('#ProductPrice').val().replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,""));

$(document).on('keyup', '#ProductPrice', function() {
if (Number($('#ProductPrice').val().replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,"")) > original_value) {
    $("#ProductPrice").css("color","red");
} else {
    $("#ProductPrice").css("color", "black");   
}
});
```

This works Fine for me.

Comment: Just FYI, the OP has a string of questions all related to the same problem. This was supposed to be on a `contenteditable` element but the OP left it out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be loading jQuery in no-conflict mode, or not loading it at all.

See this question & my answer to it:

[jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct/10807227#10807227)