# JQuery on Wordpress issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

> I'm geting an Uncaught TypeError: Object is not a function

on WordPress when trying to filter a table using jQuery,
my code is the following one.
It works when it's not under WordPress so
I guess I'm missing some kind of wrapping code on some function

Thanks to anyone who can save me in here!

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = true;
    //<![CDATA[ 
    jQuery(window).load(function($) {
        jQuery("#searchInput").keyup(function($) {
            //split the current value of searchInput

            //create a jquery object of the rows
            var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr");
            if (this.value == "") {
                jo.show();
                return;
            }
            //hide all the rows
            jo.hide();

            //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
            jo.filter(function(i, v) {
                var $t = $(this);
                for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
                    if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            })
                    //show the rows that match.
                    .show();
        }).focus(function() {
            this.value = "";
            $(this).css({
                "color": "black"
            });
            $(this).unbind('focus');
        }).css({
            "color": "#C0C0C0"
        });
    });//]]>  
</script>
```

Comment: You're getting his error on which line ?

Comment: Does your Wordpress template include a reference to the jQuery library?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would throw that, unless you're doing `window.jQuery = {}` somewhere before this code. If you hadn't included jquery you would instead get undefined isn't a function.

Comment: Hi @enguerranws I got this exact error
(anonymous function) ?eventid=9600&submit=Submit:226
x.event.dispatch jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:4
v.handle jquery.js?ver=1.10.2:4

Comment: @KevinB no, this is the first jquery of the code, but had to double check, so thanks for the hint

Comment: @Saikios I was wrong, the answer below completely explains why it is happening. I would expect the code in your question to not work anywhere due to overriding `$` in the event handlers.

Comment: @KevinB but you can check it working on the fiddle I posted as a comment down there :(

Comment: Look very closely at your fiddle and the code in your question. there's a very important difference. This spot in particular... `...Input").keyup(function () {...` which is line 5 above.

Comment: @KevinB thanks a lot for the help, my error is not mentioning this before, but if I leave it as it is it will show a lot of errors, explained in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `.load()` handler (*and `keyup`*) is an Event object, these methods don't work like `.ready()` method, the first argument of the `.ready()` handler refers to jQuery which is useful for avoiding conflicts with other libraries that use `$`. So you are (*mis*)using an Event object as jQuery.

Comment: Not my code, but here you have the original JSFIDDLE :)
http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/3/