# JS: Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my js script:

```
<script language="javascript">

setTimeout ( "autoForward()" , 5000 );
function autoForward() {
    var submitForm = $("#submitfrm").find("form");
    submitForm.submit();
}
</script>
```

And the error occurs at:

```
var submitForm = $("#submitfrm").find("form");
```

I'm using jQuery and I noticed [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct) but when I tried to add it:

```
<script language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

setTimeout ( "autoForward()" , 5000 );
function autoForward() {
    var submitForm = $("#submitfrm").find("form");
    submitForm.submit();
}

});
</script>
```

I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: autoForward is not defined
```

I also tried to switch the function's position but it didn't help. What's wrong here?

Comment: In snippet two, you used quotes around your function, meaning you're targeting a global function. You didn't define the function in the global scope. Better to not target a global function and instead target the one in the scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
setTimeout (autoForward , 5000 );
```

instead of:

```
setTimeout ("autoForward()" , 5000 );
```

You don't need any quote `"` or bracket `()` here.