# anchor link to multiple classes instead of id's with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with up and down arrows that are links that float on the left. I want them to navigate between div's on the page as a scrolling anchor links. Here is what I have so far.....I know the jquery is far from complete but I think im going in the right direction. Any help would be great.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/t8uaQ/

HTML:

```
<ul id="et-float-menu">
   <li class="et-float-menu-item1">
       <a href="#scroll"> <span><img></span> </a>
   </li>
   <li class="et-float-menu-item2">
       <a href="#scroll"> <span><img></span> </a>
   </li>
</ul>     
<div class="jumptosection" id="section1">
   <h2>Section 1</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dapibus luctus ligula sit amet tincidunt. Aliquam dapibus ipsum ac metus interdum congue. In sed arcu et quam semper tincidunt vel non enim. Ut sit amet volutpat neque. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum cursus erat vitae posuere mattis. Integer eleifend eleifend fermentum.</p>

   <p>Curabitur arcu tortor, tincidunt in ante ornare, aliquam pulvinar nunc. Quisque elit erat, suscipit non odio a, fringilla fermentum dui. Aenean ultricies nisi vitae massa fermentum facilisis. Donec dignissim iaculis tortor ultrices dapibus.</p>
</div>    
<div class="jumptosection" id="section2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dapibus luctus ligula sit amet tincidunt. Aliquam dapibus ipsum ac metus interdum congue. In sed arcu et quam semper tincidunt vel non enim. Ut sit amet volutpat neque. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum cursus erat vitae posuere mattis. Integer eleifend eleifend fermentum.</p>

    <p>Curabitur arcu tortor, tincidunt in ante ornare, aliquam pulvinar nunc. Quisque elit erat, suscipit non odio a, fringilla fermentum dui. Aenean ultricies nisi vitae massa fermentum facilisis. Donec dignissim iaculis tortor ultrices dapibus.</p>
</div>    
<div class="jumptosection" id="section3">
    <h2>Section 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dapibus luctus ligula sit amet tincidunt. Aliquam dapibus ipsum ac metus interdum congue. In sed arcu et quam semper tincidunt vel non enim. Ut sit amet volutpat neque. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum cursus erat vitae posuere mattis. Integer eleifend eleifend fermentum.</p>

    <p>Curabitur arcu tortor, tincidunt in ante ornare, aliquam pulvinar nunc. Quisque elit erat, suscipit non odio a, fringilla fermentum dui. Aenean ultricies nisi vitae massa fermentum facilisis. Donec dignissim iaculis tortor ultrices dapibus.</p>
</div>    
<div class="jumptosection" id="section4">
    <h2>Section 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dapibus luctus ligula sit amet tincidunt. Aliquam dapibus ipsum ac metus interdum congue. In sed arcu et quam semper tincidunt vel non enim. Ut sit amet volutpat neque. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum cursus erat vitae posuere mattis. Integer eleifend eleifend fermentum.</p>

    <p>Curabitur arcu tortor, tincidunt in ante ornare, aliquam pulvinar nunc. Quisque elit erat, suscipit non odio a, fringilla fermentum dui. Aenean ultricies nisi vitae massa fermentum facilisis. Donec dignissim iaculis tortor ultrices dapibus.</p>
</div>
```

MY CSS:

```
#section1 {
  padding:20px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
}

#section2 {
  padding:20px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#e8e8e8;
}

#section3 {
  padding:20px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#f8f8f8;
}

#section4 {
  padding:20px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#e8e8e8;
}

#et-float-menu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 11;
  left: 0;
  top: 45%;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

#et-float-menu a {
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

#et-float-menu a:hover { color: #b2b2b2; transition: color 300ms ease 0s; }

#et-float-menu li {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
}


.et-float-menu-item a { display: inline-block; font-size: 24px; position: relative; text-align: center; transition: color 300ms ease 0s; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
.et-float-menu-item a:hover { color: #a0a0a0; }
.et-social-icon span { display: none; }
.et-float-menu-item1 a:before { content: '↑';font-size:22px; }
.et-float-menu-item2 a:before { content: '↓';font-size:22px; }
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var jumptosectionTopPosition = jQuery('.jumptosection').offset().top;
jQuery('#scroll').click(function(){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:jumptosectionTopPosition}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: you have the href set as #scroll there is no element with scroll set as id, also you cannot have more than one element have the same id if that was a typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `href`s of your `<a>` to `scrollUp` and `scrollDown` correspondingly.

Stick to some `.selected` class, which will be used for identifying current selected section.
Add this class to the first section in html.

Add a function that will perform **selection**: by adding `.selected` class and scrolling to newly selected `div`.

```
function changeSelection(sectionFrom, sectionTo) {
    if(sectionTo.length > 0) {
        sectionFrom.removeClass("selected");
        sectionTo.addClass("selected");
        $("body").animate({scrollTop: sectionTo.offset().top});
    }
}
```

Attach `click` listeners to your `anchor`s. Inside each of them find current selected `div` and `div` you want to be **selected** and call `changeSelection()` using these `div`s.

For `scrollDown` we want to **select** the next `div`:

```
$(document).on("click", "[href='#scrollDown']", function(){
    var currentSection = $(".selected");
    var nextSection = currentSection.next(".jumptosection");

    changeSelection(currentSection, nextSection);

    return false;
});
```

For `scrollUp` we want to **select** the previous `div`:

```
$(document).on("click", "[href='#scrollUp']", function(){
    var currentSection = $(".selected");
    var prevSection = currentSection.prev(".jumptosection");

    changeSelection(currentSection, prevSection);

    return false;
});
```

In case you reach the end (the first or the last `.jumptosection` `div`), nothing will be changed (it is controlled by the `changeSelection` function - it checks do we have **sectionWeWantScrollTo**)

## Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/t8uaQ/4/)

---

## Edited (for http://94co.com/client3/about/)

1. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807237/991954) about WordPress and jQuery. Use `jQuery` instead of
   `$` in your script
2. It is better to use `id` instead of `href` on `anchor`
3. Make sure you wrap JavaScript of `click` listeners in

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        /*scrollUp and scrollDown click listeners should be here*/
   });
   ```

   (JSFiddle makes this wrap automatically). `changeSelection` function doesn't need to be wrapped

## Here is the updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/t8uaQ/8/)

Comment: Demo works perfectly...thank you again. If you have a second could you look at it here: http://94co.com/client3/about/  Doesn't seem to be working for some reason but its all in the source.

Comment: Wrap listeners in `$(document).ready(function(){/*listeners are here*/});`

Comment: Also, use `jQuery` instead of `$` (details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct))

Answer (score 1):

You can set some initial `var` that let you know the start point like this:

```
var pre = $('.et-float-menu-item1'),
    nex = $('.et-float-menu-item2'),
    act = $('#section1');
```

<sub>Where act is the start</sub>

And then evaluate `prev` and `next` elements:

```
nex.click(function(){
    pre.slideDown();
    var gt = act.next('div').offset().top;
    $('body').animate({scrollTop : gt},'slow');
    act = act.next('div');
})
pre.click(function(){
    var gt = act.prev('div').offset().top;
    $('body').animate({scrollTop : gt},'slow');
    act = act.prev('div');
})
```

This code can be improved but is the first aproach I can give.

Check the **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8uaQ/1/)**