# jQuery transit on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, jquery-transit

fairly new at jQuery having trouble working out how to get jQuery transit working on hover.

```
$(".rotate").hover(function(){
    $(this).transition({
      perspective: '100px',
      rotateY: '180deg'
    });
});
```

This returns "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function", I've been messing with this for a while but seem to be going in circles.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks
Frank

Comment: Have you included JQuery library?

Comment: provide your output in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, it ended up being the wordpress version of jquery

see here [jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct#answer-10807237)

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

CSS is better in every way:

```css
.rotate {
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
    perspective: 100px;
}
.rotate:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Just sayin' ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine, i just put it into a [fiddle quickly.....](http://jsfiddle.net/PWBrK/) Have you definitely included both jQuery and the transit.js library?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .rotate{ width:50px; height:50px; background-color:lightgrey; border:1px solid #000;  }
</style>
<div class='rotate'></div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".rotate").hover(function(){
    $(this).transition({
      perspective: '100px',
      rotateY: '180deg'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: jquery should be before the transit js

Comment: Very true...... that's what you get for checking it in jsfiddle (where jQuery is added for you) before copying and pasting it across!!!

Comment: jQuery is definitely added, its in use for other elements already. I've check that code, I see it works fine in the fiddle. The error is still returning in chromes console.

'Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function (index):264
(anonymous function)'

Comment: Which line actually is it? if you click on the line number on the right in chromes console it should show you the line of code causing the issue..... do you have any other library's included? try replacing the $ sign with jQuery e.g. jQuery(".rotate").hover(function(){