# TypeError '$' is not a function : Phonegap in android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

`jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js` , 
`jquery-ui.js(1.10.4)` ,`jquery-1.9.1.js`  not working on Android emulator using **Phonegap**.

Its showing error as `"Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object \[object Window\] is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct)

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct
plz check if solution works in your case

Comment: Load jquery.min.js or jquery.js, not both of them. If you face any problems , load jquery-ui after JQM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery core library first before `jQuery UI` and `jQuery Mobile`, correct order should be:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Also make sure that all the files are loaded properly with correct path as well as your custom jQuery code is running after you've included all of the relevant scripts. In above example, you can put your code inside `scripts.js` file.

Comment: I have included libraries in following order:                              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: This works partially. But $.mobile.loading( 'show');, this tag is not working.