# Joomla com media image select Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function index.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools

I'm building a website in Joomla 3.1, within the Zoo area it uses the Com_media to select for the image. I can use it to browser images, but the pop up gives the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`

While browsing the images and clicking on the one I want to use I get the second error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'populateFields' of undefined`

Any help to resolve these would be great.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery Library ?

Comment: `<script src="/solent/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/solent/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/solent/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` Here the Jquery I found, it also loads mooltools as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load [jQuery noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), the dollar sign `$` stops beying connected to jQuery. So you should use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`.

Keep in mind that MooTools also uses the dollar sign. [This MooTools method](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollar) is for selecting a element by ID and can be replaced by `document.id()`

The tricky part, if you have both MooTools and jQuery code is to know which library the dollar bellongs to. In [the error you pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807200/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-property-of-object-object-window-is-not-a-funct) above I think its just to replace the `$` by `jQuery`ar the line of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `$` to `jQuery` where the error is occurring in your code. It is my understading that the issue occurs due to the no conflict jQuery file being loaded in by Joomla:

`<script src="/solent/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: It seems the $ is for calling Mooltools rather than Jquery